# INNER JOIN not returning any rows

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I'm trying to get customer names from the database who do not have any events in April 2015:

```
SELECT customer.customerId, customer.Name, event.Date
FROM customer
INNER JOIN event ON event.customerId=customer.customerId
INNER JOIN 
    (
    SELECT eventId AS evid, customerId
    FROM  event
    WHERE year(event.Date)=2015 AND month(event.Date)=04
    GROUP BY customerId
    )
EV ON event.eventId = EV.evid
WHERE event.customerId IS NULL
```

I'm getting zero rows, I should have approx. 20 customer names there. What's wrong with the query?

Comment: Why do you expect NULL Id's after INNER joins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a left join, and you only need to join in the table once. You can't select an event date though, as you are getting customers *without* any events in the interval:

```
select
  customer.customerId, customer.Name
from
  customer
  left join event on event.customerId = customer.customerId
    and year(event.Date) = 2015 and month(event.Date) = 4
where
  event.customerId is null
```

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the customer id and name of all the customers that don't have any events in april 2015:

```
SELECT customer.customerId, customer.Name
FROM customer
WHERE customerId NOT IN
(
    SELECT customerId
    FROM  event
    WHERE year(event.Date)=2015 AND month(event.Date)=04
) EV;
```